# Passing Php variable it Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hi I'm trying to pass a php variable from **produto.php** to another file **descProduto.php** it ajax but without success. Please someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong? The ajax is working but I can't get the value on descProduto.php

This is where I click produto.php

```
<img class="btn-details" src="plus.png" data-idproduto="'.$idproduto.'"/>
```

My ajax ( diferent file ajax.js)

```
$(function(){
    $(".btn-details").on('click', function(){

        var idproduto = $(this).data('idproduto');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "descProduto.php",
            async: false,
            dataType: "html",
            data: {'idproduto': idproduto},
            success: function(result){
                console.log("success");
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log("error");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Where I get the variable descProduto.php

```
if(isset($_POST['idproduto'])){
    $idproduto = $_POST['idproduto'];
    echo $idproduto;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If you look at the html output of product.php, does data-idproduto contain the actual id, or not.

Comment: Yes it contain the problem is not receving in descProduto.php

Comment: Could you please show up the output of **print_r($_POST);** on descProduto.php file!?

Comment: i tested this code it works. i forgot to include jquery but when added it worked. i hope this is not the case with u

Comment: Work for you but don't work for me. print_r($_POST) don't print anything, prints a empty array. Print Array ( )

Answer (score 0):

Why using AJAX ? .You can't use for this matter.just use session

In page1.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['var'] = 'foo'
```

In Page2.php

```
echo $_SESSION['var']; //foo
```

Comment: For what I want have to be it ajax.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check whether your `$idproduto` actually prints on produto.php (Developer Tools/ FireBug/ View Source).

Then `console.log(idproduto)` **before** sending the ajax post to see whether it sets correctly.

Comment: Yes it prints the problem is not receving on descProduto.php

Comment: Print all variables in descProduto.php and see whether your param is there as below.
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>

Also print request body stream to see whether the variables are attached to request.

var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")));

Comment: the idproduto is set before send the ajax request I tested. print_r($_POST) don't print anything, prints a empty array. Print Array ( ). Don't now what is wrong the code looks fine for me.

Comment: @Jay You have to do print_r($_POST) in descProduto.php.
Also did you do below in descProduto.php? 

var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")));

Comment: Harshadewa I allready print_r($_POST) and print a empty array() also var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")));  print NULL. Any ideias?